# Ionic2 Typescript - Dictionery Inside array, how to access value - Suggestion for better approach

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

Currently I am using Ionic2 Storage module to store data.

My Homepage has list of videos, I want to store Favorites from home page with two inputs. VideoId and VideoTitle.

I am looking for suggestion on below:

1. Is my approach correct to store favorites i.e. Storing all favorites
   inside one key **myFav**
2. If this is right approach how to check for already saved videoId so
   I need not store same detail as favorite again. Do I need to loop through all elements?

   ```
   setFavourite(videoId,title){
     this.storage.get('myFav').then((data) => {
     this.fav = { "videoId" :videoId , "title" : title }
     if(data != null)
     { data.push((this.fav));
       this.storage.set('myFav', data);
     }
     else
     {
       let array = [];
       array.push((this.fav));
       this.storage.set('myFav', array);
     }   
   });
   ```

   }
3. If my approach is not correct, and you suggest that i should store
   data as videoId : title i.e each videoId will be key and title will
   be value in the database.

   ```
   setFavourite(videoId,title){
      this.storage.set(videoId, title);
   }
   ```
4. if point 3 right approach, How can i get all the list of favorite
   videos on favorites component so I can list them on favorites page
   for user.

   ```
   getFavorites(){
      this.storage.get('WhatShouldbeMyKeyHere').then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
   }
   ```

Thank you

Comment: I would combine 2 approachs. 1stores list  of favorite and 3 stores each item.

Comment: Thank you @Nguyen,  so for existence check I should use the output of step 3. And for showing the list on other component I can use the list created on step 1.